# OnPropertyChanged 2nd level update

Tags: c#, wpf, binding, inotifypropertychanged

Searching didn't bring me any clues and I am sort of at a loss.
WPF is self taught so far, so I might be overlooking something simple.

```
<Window.DataContext>
    <local:MainViewModel/>
</Window.DataContext>

<TextBlock Text={Binding BoundTextProperty}"/>
```

that's the simplified xml

```
public class MainViewModel
{
    private Model Data;
    public MainViewModel()
    {...}
    public string BoundTextProperty => Data.BoundTextProperty;
    ...
}
```

The Property that's bound referencing the Property holding the Data in the model

```
public class Model : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private long number;
    public long Number
    {
        get { return number; }
        set 
        {
            number = value;
            OnPropertyChanged(nameof(BoundTextProperty));
        }
    }

    public string BoundTextProperty => $"Some text {Number} some text again";

    public virtual event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
}
```

I swear it worked at some point.
The string has a couple other variables, but that's the basic of how it works or rather doesn't.

My Question is wether or not the Binding can actually bubble up, and if it can, why doesn't it?

Comment: No it doesn't bubble up automatically, you have to call `OnPropertyChanged` also in the `MainViewModel`, e.g. by handling the `PropertyChanged` event for `Data`, e.g. like `Data.PropertyChanged += ... handler that calls OnPropertyChanged ...` .

Comment: It definitely won't bubble up by default. I would also highly recommend not muddying your `Model` class with the `INotifyPropertyChanged` interface. Your model should be agnostic of the MVVM / binding architecture. Property changed events should always come from your ViewModels.

Comment: To add another *opinion*, it's perfectly valid to implement INotifyPropertyChanged in a model class. Doing so does not violate the MVVM pattern, and especially doesn't "muddy" anything.

Comment: so no OnPropertyChanged calls in the model at all?
edit: that's exactly why wpf is confusing, since everyone does it in a different way

Comment: It's not technically wrong, but it's a code smell that tells you that you are likely directly modifying your data model's properties from the UI, which is often a recipe for disaster. Wrapping the boilerplate property changed logic in ViewModels can be a hassle, but I feel it pays off in the end. But there are definitely multiple schools of thought about this.

Comment: @FrankM could you elaborate in an answer how to implement that correctly?

Comment: I agree with @Clemens that implementing INotifyPropertyChanged on MVVM models is perfectly OK. In my daily job, we are using that pattern all time and had no problem with it.

Comment: I have INotifyPropertyChangedImplemented on both Model and ViewModel, since some data makes more sense to be in the viewModel than the model

Comment: That's ok. And don't take "code smell" comments too serious.

Comment: I am open to try suggestions, and if it helps keeping the code more readably then why not? I wasn't going to throw away what I did ^^

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to add the code for bubbling up the Model's PropertyChanged event from the ViewModel to the View.
Here is an example (based on your code):

```
public class MainViewModel : ViewModelBase
{
    private readonly Model Data;

    public MainViewModel()
    {
        Data = new Model();
        Data.PropertyChanged += ModelOnPropertyChanged;
    }

    private void ModelOnPropertyChanged(object sender, PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        switch (e.PropertyName)
        {
            case nameof(Model.BoundTextProperty):
                OnPropertyChanged(nameof(MainViewModel.BoundTextProperty));
                break;
            // add cases for other properties here:
        }
    }

    public string BoundTextProperty => Data.BoundTextProperty;
}

public class Model : ModelBase
{
    private long number;
    public long Number
    {
        get { return number; }
        set
        {
            number = value;
            OnPropertyChanged(nameof(BoundTextProperty));
        }
    }

    public string BoundTextProperty => $"Some text {Number} some text again";

}

public abstract class ViewModelBase : Base
{
    // add other ViewModel related stuff here
}


public abstract class ModelBase : Base
{
    // add other Model related stuff here
}

public abstract class Base : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public virtual event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks a lot, I especially like the Base, haven't thought of that.

I'll ask a follow up, since I am now kinda doubting my structural setup..

Answer (score 1):

You need to raise the `PropertyChanged` event for the source property that you bind to in your XAML. In this case you bind to the `BoundTextProperty` of the `MainViewModel` which means that the `MainViewModel` class should raise the `PropertyChanged` event.

It doesn't matter whether the source property wraps another property of a class that does raise the `PropertyChanged` event. It's the source object of the binding that notifies the view.

You could also just bind to the "model" property directly, provided that you turn `Data` into a public property in your view model:

```
public Model Data { get; private set; }
...
<TextBlock Text="{Binding Data.BoundTextProperty}"/>
```

If you choose to stick with your wrapper property, the `MainViewModel` must implement the `INotifyPropertyChanged` event and raise the `PropertyChanged` event whenever the model is updated:

```
public class MainViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private readonly Model Data;

    public MainViewModel()
    {
        Data = new Model();
        Data.PropertyChanged += Data_PropertyChanged;
    }

    private void Data_PropertyChanged(object sender, PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        OnPropertyChanged("BoundTextProperty");
    }

    public string BoundTextProperty => Data.BoundTextProperty;

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
}
```

Comment: for that to work, I would have to set the property in the mainViewModel, which I don't. Meaning that the OnProperty wouldn't know the Data property changed

Comment: What does "that" mean? If you bind to `Data.BoundTextProperty` in your XAML, the `TextBlock` will be updated when you set the property of the model. If you bind to the view model property, you don't need to set this property but you need to raise the `PropertyChanged` event for it as I explained in my answer.

Comment: I was referring to the first part in your answer, the rest is correct, but it doesn't help me, since I wanted the verification of the data in the mainViewModel, meaning I also need the binding there.

Comment: "The rest is correct"? The first part is certainly also correct. If you bind to the view model property and update the model property, the view model should subscribe to the model's `PropertyChanged` event and raise its own `PropertyChanged` event whenever the model property is changed. How is the view otherwise supposed to know that the model property has changed?

Comment: I tried that, it didn't work, which is why I asked the question

Comment: Show you you tried then. Obviously you did it wrong if it doesn't work.

Comment: I edited my answer to provide an example of you you could implement the view model to listen to model changes.